# ubuntu 14.04 Apache 403 error befor logging in

Tags: apache-httpd

I have an ubuntu Desktop version with LAMP SERVER installed on it
when I restart the server and try to access it over the network I get Error 403 forbidden but after I login to that system from ssh or directly on that system I can view the files over network.
I checked Apache error.log:

```
[Thu Sep 03 07:36:24.360012 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 1243] [client 192.168.1.130:43895] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/USERNAME/public_html
[Thu Sep 03 07:36:24.802882 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 1243] [client 192.168.1.130:43895] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/USERNAME/public_html
[Thu Sep 03 07:36:31.539698 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 1244] [client 192.168.1.130:43896] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/USERNAME/public_html
[Thu Sep 03 07:36:31.603388 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 1244] [client 192.168.1.130:43896] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/USERNAME/public_html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your server configuration. There should be a `<Directory>` entry for your document root. I guess it says something like

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Change that to `Allow from all`, but only for the document root, not the root directory or other sensitive area.